# How to set GIT_COMMITTER_NAME and GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL

Tags: git, environment-variables, gerrit

I am trying to set and unset the following GIT enviroment variables as below, somehow the commands dont work,what commands should I run to set these?

```
GIT_COMMITTER_NAME
GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL
```

Running the commands

```
set GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Test attempt"
echo $GIT_COMMITTER_NAME --> shows as empty
```

UPDATE:-

```
import os
os.system('export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=\'Test try\'')
print(os.getenv("GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"))
```

Comment: What OS? What shell (command interpreter)? Why tag [gerrit]?

Comment: it is on MACOS and linux using bash

Answer (score 0):

Edit (per update); original answer below.

> ```
> import os
> os.system('export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME=\'Test try\'')
> print(os.getenv("GIT_COMMITTER_NAME"))
> ```

This is sure to fail, because `os.system` fires up a *new* shell.  The new shell inherits the environment from its parent process (Python), changes its own environment to provide `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME` to commands invoked *from* the shell, and then has nothing left to do, so the new shell promptly terminates, returning a zero exit status to `os.system` (which waits for the shell to terminate).

At this time, the shell that has changed its environment is *gone:* there is nothing left of it.  The parent Python process still exists, and still has its own original environment.

If you are writing Python code, you can use `os.putenv` to change the *Python* process's environment, or you can use the `subprocess` module.  The latter provides a series of functions including `Popen`, `call`, and `check_call`, all of which take an optional `env` dictionary.  If you provide an `env` dictionary, that becomes the environment of the called process.  Hence:

```
>>> import os
>>> import subprocess
>>> env = os.environ.copy()
>>> env['T'] = 'hello'
>>> subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', 'echo $T'], env=env)
hello
0
>>> env['T'] = 'jello'
>>> subprocess.call(['sh', '-c', 'echo $T'], env=env)
jello
0
```

(the `0`s here are the result of each interactive `subprocess.call`).

There is no particular reason to favor one way or the other at this particular level, but `subprocess.Popen` offers a lot more flexibility and power (at the cost of requiring more code on your own part) than does `os.system`.

---

#### Original answer

Different shells use different syntax tricks or commands to set or export shell variables.

The most common methods, which work in POSIX shells and bash, are:

- `export variable=value`, e.g., `export GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Noah Body"`
- `variable=value command`, e.g., `GIT_COMMITTER_NAME="Noah Body" GIT_COMMITTER_EMAIL=nobody@example.com git commit`

The former sets the variable's value and exports it for the duration of the remainder of the script (or to where it is changed or unset: see below).  The latter sets the variable's value and exports it for the single command that is being run.

If a variable is already set-and-exported, changing its value normally keeps the variable exported.  For instance:

```
$ export T=test
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("T"))'
test
$ T=again
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("T"))'
again
```

Using `unset variable` removes the variable from both the shell's tables *and* the environment:

```
$ unset T
$ python -c 'import os; print(os.getenv("T"))'
None
```

The keyword `set` in front of the expression causes the arguments to be set as *shell* arguments:

```
$ echo "$#: $@"
: 
$ set A=B c d
$ echo "$#: $@"
3: A=B c d
```

Other shells (non-POSIX and not bash) may differ in behavior.

Comment: I tried al the 3 ways using export,set,using variable value,I always get a`None` as value

Comment: The above works for me in bash on a Linux system, when cut and pasted (leave out the `$` of course).

Comment: I updated the python script I used to set the environment variable,it works through CLI but not through python

Comment: Ah. You can't *do* that. Environment variables are inherited downward only. Will update answer.